# Java reflection superClass loaded by hibernate problems

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I am trying to print in console the names of the fields of a superClass i needed for a later computing is working OK when is a simple POJO but when the class is previously loaded by Hibernate i am getting the fields of the child not the superClass and when i print the name of the parent (when loaded by Hibernate i am getting the following)

[handler,_filter_signature,serialVersionUID,*methods*]

here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    FixingModels clazz = new FixingModels();
    HibernateHandler handler = new HibernateHandler(true);
    Student student =  (Student)handler.getSession().load(Student.class,1);
    Student newStudent = new Student();
    System.out.println("Printing Class loaded by Hibernate");
    clazz.showFieldsFromSuperClass(student);//show the Fields of the Child and parent wrong
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Printing Class instance by new..");
    clazz.showFieldsFromSuperClass(newStudent);//Show the fields from the parent and child IS O.K
}
private void showFieldsFromSuperClass(Student clazz) 
{
    final Class objectClass = clazz.getClass();
    final Class parentClass = objectClass.getSuperclass();
    System.out.println("Printing Child");
    for(Field field:objectClass.getDeclaredFields())System.out.println(field.getName());//printing child
    System.out.println("Printing Parent");
    for(Field field:parentClass.getDeclaredFields())System.out.println(field.getName());//printing parent
}
```

the first time

```
clazz.showFieldsFromSuperClass(student);
```

is called is printing [handler,_filter_signature,serialVersionUID,*methods*] later the the fields from the child is like the hibernate is now the parent of my student class not my abstract class in code. later

```
clazz.showFieldsFromSuperClass(newStudent);
```

is printing the right fields the student fields as well it's parent Person in this case

my question is how can i get the Person class fields[Parent Class] whenever comes from new instance of by hibernate or by Spring container??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate load() method doesn't fully initialize the retrieved object, but returns a proxy until you access an object property.

You can get the correct `Class` of the object without initializing it using a special hibernate helper class:

`HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(student);`

Comment: thanks for all the people you helped me on this issue i have found very useful... all the solutions.. god bless.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I suspect Hibernate is creating another subclass of your "child class" on the fly - and creating an instance of that when you fetch it from the session. Your code is currently relying on the instance being a *direct* instance of *just* `Student`.

This is easy to verify:

```
System.out.println("Instance class: " + objectClass);
```

I suspect what it prints is *not* what you're expecting to see.

Given that you *know* the parent class you want (the superclass of `Student`, presumably) why not just refer to that explicitly using a class literal?

Comment: i am getting the following the class when loaded by hibernate. [Parent->Child]
Loaded by Hibernate: Student Student_$$_javassist_21
Instance by new: Person Student.

Comment: @javiut: Right, so that ties in with what my suspicion. So if you know the class you want to use already, just use a class literal.